# why implementing in matlab planar array formula went wrong

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have tried to implement the formula shown below in matlab to create the plot shown below.

[image]

[image]

But when I implemented the formula using the code below I get a totally different plot as shown below.

Where did I go wrong?

```
[theta,phi] = meshgrid(-pi:0.2:0.5*pi,-pi:0.2:pi);
f=10;
lambda=300/f;
k=(2*pi)/lambda;
N=10;
M=10;
dx=0.5*lambda;
dy=0.5*lambda;
ksi_x=k*dx.*sin(theta).*cos(phi);
ksi_y=k*dy.*sin(theta).*sin(phi);
AF=((1/M)*((sin(0.5*M*ksi_x))./(sin(0.5*ksi_x)))).*((1/N)*((sin(0.5*N*ksi_y))./(sin(0.5*ksi_y))));

surf(phi,theta,AF)
colorbar
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plots you provided are not based on (Θ, φ), they're of Ψ_x and Ψ_y.

Just replace `surf(phi,theta,AF)` with `surf(ksi_y, ksi_x, AF)` and you'll have it.

[image: surf]